# Why do I get multiple digits on an indexing + question mark operator on a string?

Tags: c#, conditional-operator

When I run the following code

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string s = "480";
        Console.WriteLine(1 == -1 ? 0 : s[1]);
        Console.WriteLine(s[1]);
    }
}
```

I get

```
56
8
```

I don't understand how I get 56.

Comment: One of the downsides of the conditional operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Documentation on the ?: Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator:)

> "Either the type of first_expression and second_expression must be the same, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other."

and

> "The conditional operator is right-associative."

So your result becomes a numeric in the first case, and a char in the second case.

Answer (score 5):

Your `0 : s[1]` converts the `char` in `s[1]` to an integer. And the value of `8` in the ASCII table is `56`.

You want to use a `char` on the left hand side too (using single quotes):

```
Console.WriteLine(1 == -1 ? '0' : s[1]);
```

Comment: Or better assign the return value of the conditional operator to a variable(neither `var` nor `object` but `char`) to minimize the risk of such issues. He would have got a compiler error then.

Answer (score 3):

> I don't understand how I get 56.

in the first line it is interpreted as UTF-16 code of the char `8`:

```
Console.WriteLine(1 == -1 ? 0 : s[1]);
```

Using the conditional operator you give here the choice between an `int` `0` and a `char` so the compiler converts the latter implicitly to an `int` (which gives you the UTF-16 code) and prints it to the console

and in the second line you actually get the `char` value printed

```
Console.WriteLine(s[1]);
```

No implicit conversion happens here.

Comment: @PatrikHofman thank you for the edit, too early for proper english syntax apparently ;)

Answer (score 2):

s[1] is the int value of the char.

The question operator implies an integer from the zero meaning it is an int. It converts the char to int.